# Javascript help, writing html elements

Tags: javascript

How do I write this HTML using javascript.

```
<div id="resizeControl">
    <input type="image" src="resuce.png" />
    <input type="image" src="enlarge.png" />
</div>
```

and append it to a slidegallery object..

.net

Answer (score 5):

```
var image1= document.createElement("input"); //create your input
image1.setAttribute('src','resuce.png'); //set the attributes
image1.setAttribute('type','image');

var image2= document.createElement("input");
image2.setAttribute('src','enlarge.png');
image2.setAttribute('type','image');

var resizeControl = document.createElement("div"); //create the parent div
resizeControl.id = "resizeControl"; //assign the id
resizeControl.appendChild(image1);  //append your images to the new div
resizeControl.appendChild(image2);

document.body.appendChild(resizeControl); //append the div to your body (or other element)
```

**Code example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/hkN7L/1/)**

More information on concepts used:

1. [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.appendChild)
2. [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createElement)
3. [`element.setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute)

Comment: innerHTML makes your js code very stringy +1 for not using innerHTML

Answer (score 3):

```
var div = document.createElement('div'),
input1 = document.createElement('input'),
input2 = document.createElement('input');

div.id = 'resizeControl';

input1.type = 'image';
input1.src = 'resuce.png';

input2.type = 'image';
input2.src = 'enlarge.png';

div.appendChild(input1);
div.appendChild(input2);

document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("Main").innerHTML += "<strong>Hello!</strong>";
document.getElementById("Main").innerHTML += "<div style='background:red'>Rrrrred!</div>";
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Main">
    Why... 
</div>
```